# Can the EMC grab utility be used on ESX hosts

Tags: storage, vmware-esx, emc

Can the EMC grab utility be used on ESX hosts?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used it on ESX 3.5 hosts, but if I remember correctly, not every version of it worked. You might have to ask EMC for a different version if it doesn't.